Flutter JS Interop parse Object
I'm using new dart:js_interop.
I'm getting arbitrary object from JS. All I know about it is that is of JSON type. i.e. equivalent of Dart Map<String, dynamic>.
Is there a way to get its properties without converting using Extension type?
In other words, get reference to JSObject and read its properties from Dart.
